# Search for a combination in dataframe to change cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace values in a column if the a combination of values in two columns is valid. Lets say I have the following `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Texas 1', '111', '222', '333'],
        ['Texas 1', '444', '555', '666'],
        ['Texas 2', '777','888','999']
    ])

         0    1    2    3
0  Texas 1  111  222  333
1  Texas 1  444  555  666
2  Texas 2  777  888  999
```

And if I want to replace the value in `column 2` if `column 0 = Texas 1` and the value of `column 2 = 222`I'm doing the following:

```
df.ix[ (df.Column 0=='Texas 1')&(df.Column 2 =='222'),Column 2] = "Success"
```

That works fine for a few combinations. The part where I'm lost is how to do this for over 300 combinations? I thought maybe I could use a `dict` and store the key, which would be `'Success'` or whatever other value. And the list could be the combination. Kind of like this.

```
a["Success"] = [Texas 1, 222]
>>> a
{"Success": [Texas 1, 222]}
```

But I'm not sure how to do that in a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all almost all your code, just create `dictionary` or `list` and iterate over it and you are done.

```
import pandas as pd
combinations = [['key1', 'key2', 'msg']]
combinations.append(['Texas 1', '222', 'triple two'])
combinations.append(['Texas 1', '555', 'triple five'])

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Texas 1', '111', '222', '333'],
        ['Texas 1', '444', '555', '666'],
        ['Texas 2', '777','888','999']
    ])

for c in combinations:
    df.ix[(df[0] == c[0]) & (df[2] == c[1]), 1] = c[2]
```

Output:

```
         0            1    2    3
0  Texas 1   triple two  222  333
1  Texas 1  triple five  555  666
2  Texas 2          777  888  999
```

Comment: This gave me exactly what I was looking for. What are the differences between using a dictionary or a list for this particular example?

Comment: In this particular example in really doesn't matter. Dictionaries are more convenient but slower and don't preserve the order, while lists are faster and preserve the order. In terms of semantics it doesn't really make sense to use a dictionary here, e.g. what if two different value pair should give the same result? what is the key, what is the value?

Answer (score 0):

## Great Use Case for `DataFrame.apply()`. Lamda functions all the way!!

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Texas 1', 111, 222, 333],
        ['Texas 1', 444, 555, 666],
        ['Texas 2', 777,888,999]
    ])


val_dict = {}
# assumption
# str_like_Success : [column_0 , column_1]
val_dict["Success"] = ['Texas 1', 222]
val_dict["Failure"] = ['Texas 2', 888]
```

The function `fill_values_from_dict` will be applied to each row, where `x` is the row (Series) and `val_dict` is the dictionary created above

```
  def fill_values_from_dict(x,val_dict):
        for key,val in val_dict.items():
            if x[0] == val[0] and x[2] == val[1]:
                x.set_value(1,key)
                return x
        return x
```

Apply `fill_values_from_dict` to each row

```
df1 = df.apply(lambda x : fill_values_from_dict(x,val_dict),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   print(df1)

             0        1    2    3
    0  Texas 1  Success  222  333
    1  Texas 1      444  555  666
    2  Texas 2  Failure  888  999
```